# How to map image and text coming from different source?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

how to map image and text in html? suppose image is there in image folder and text is coming from DB? How to put them in one place in a web page?

suppose milkbottel is there in my image folder and milkbottle text is comming from the db so how to **

> map dynamically

** this two in a way that milkbottle image and milk bottle text will be in one place in a web page?

Comment: I don't really understand your question, so for specific image you have a text? If this is the case store the image filename in another field in your DB.

Comment: suppose milkbottel is there in my image folder and milkbottle text is comming from the db so how to map dynamically this two in a way that milkbottle image and milk bottle text will be in one place in a web page?

Comment: store image url in same table as text is simplest approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DB content example:

```
id (INT)   | caption VARCHAR(255)     | location VARCHAR(255)
   1              milkbottle            /images/milkbottle.jpg
   2                orange              /images/orange.jpg
```

JSP example

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<table border="2">
<%
try {
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/test";
   String username="root";
   String password="root";
   String query="SELECT * FROM image_table WHERE caption = 'milkbottle' LIMIT 1";
   Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
   Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
   ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);

   if(rs != null) {
   %>
    <tr>
      <td><%=rs.getString("caption"); %></td>
      <td><img src='<%=rs.getString("location"); %>'/></td>
    </tr>
<%
}
%>
    </table>
    <%
    rs.close();
    stmt.close();
    conn.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
%>
</body>
</form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your problem revolves around retrieving a caption (which is stored in a database) when you load a image for a webpage.

In this case, just store the location of the image in your database table along with the caption. Take a look at this sample table layout:

```
id (INT)   | caption VARCHAR(255)     | location VARCHAR(255)
```

So when you store a new image and caption, store the location where you save the image in `location`. Then you can retrieve the caption given the image location by the following query:

```
SELECT caption FROM image_table WHERE location = '/exact/location'
```

Though I must say that it is bad for to use text for `WHERE` clauses. If you can, pulling both the location and corresponding image using the table's `id` column is far better (i.e. faster).

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur effort. Appreciated.